# See all questions on Stack Overflow, sorted by upvotes/downvotes

Tags: support, stack-overflow

Is it possible to display a list of questions on Stack Exchange, sorted by the number of upvotes and downvotes? I want to find the questions on StackOverflow that are the most popular and least popular, respectively.

Comment: [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/) - Minimal SQL skills required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your interest is limited to a single SE site (e.g. StackOverflow), just go to the 'Questions' tab and click the 'Votes' sub-tab to order by votes.

I don't know if it's possible to reverse the ordering (to get lowest-ranked first), but you can just scroll down to the bottom of the question list and click on the link to the final page of results if you want to see the lowest-rated questions.

Comment: Here's the link (for meta stack overflow): http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes